# is there a way to set an array of dates all to the same Hour?

Tags: swift, date, datepicker, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I have an array of dates created from a date picker. When they are saved it also adds the hours and minutes. When I compare the dates to be equal some of them are an hour off because of daylight savings time.

Is there a way, after the date picker, to set each date to the same hour or do I have to go through the process of checking for daylight savings time and adding or subtraction an hour? Or should I run the array through a function to make them all equal?

```
func createDatePicker() {

    // format Display of date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    // assign datepicker to textfield
    dateTextField.inputView = datePicker

    // create toolbar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // add item Button
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector (doneClicked))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)


    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

@objc func doneClicked() {

    //format the date display in text field
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
    dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

    self.view.endEditing(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

found a fix.

```
if let date = dateTextField.text {
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
     newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)!
     let tz = TimeZone.current
     if tz.isDaylightSavingTime(for: newDate) {
     print("date Changed")
     newDate += 3600
```

Comment: If you just need to check if two dates are on the same day you can use calendar method `func isDate(_ date1: Date, inSameDayAs date2: Date) -> Bool`